Issue running tests with Enzyme, React 16, and Emotion 11.x
I am working on a React 16.8.x application and am in the process of updating to emotion 11.13.x. I also use Enzume v3.x and the react 16 adapter for it.
In my typical component I use the css={{}} syntax. For my babel configuration I installed  "@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop": "11.12.0", and I have this in my presets:
 presets: [
                    [
                        '@babel/preset-react',
                        {
                            runtime: 'automatic',
                            importSource: 'react'
                        }
                    ],

I have emotion working when running my app but run into issues when running my spec test files.
When running a shallow mounted enzyme test:
  it('calls some method when textarea changes', () => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(wrapper.debug());
        wrapper.find('Textarea').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'test' } });
        expect(props.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test');
    });

This is what I see logged out (I should see my  instead):
 
​'<ForwardRef is="p" css={{...}} __EMOTION_TYPE_PLEASE_DO_NOT_USE__={{...}} />
  <ForwardRef placeholder={[undefined]} rows={20} name="reviewBody" maxLength={1000} css={{...}} value="" onChange={[Function (anonymous)]} __EMOTION_TYPE_PLEASE_DO_NOT_USE__={[function]} />
  <Grid justifyContent="flex-start" theme={{...}} display="grid" gap={3} repeat="fit">
    <ForwardRef css={{...}} variant="primary" onClick={[Function: wrap] { and: SpyStrategy { identity: 'nextStep', originalFn: [Function (anonymous)], getSpy: [Function: getSpy], _defaultPlan: [Function (anonymous)], plan: [Function (anonymous)], resolveTo: [Function (anonymous)], rejectWith: [Function (anonymous)] }, withArgs: [Function (anonymous)], calls: CallTracker { track: [Function (anonymous)], any: [Function (anonymous)], count: [Function (anonymous)], argsFor: [Function (anonymous)], thisFor: [Function (anonymous)], all: [Function (anonymous)], allArgs: [Function (anonymous)], first: [Function (anonymous)], mostRecent: [Function (anonymous)], reset: [Function (anonymous)], saveArgumentsByValue: [Function (anonymous)] } }} width="177px" __EMOTION_TYPE_PLEASE_DO_NOT_USE__={{...}} />
  </Grid>'



The weird thing I see is: EMOTION_TYPE_PLEASE_DO_NOT_USE...
Why is my component being wrapped in ForwardRef? I know there's some weirdness happening with Enzyme's shallow mount + the way Emotion 11 works under the hood.
Sometimes switching to mount works and other times even switching to mount does nothing to help the tests pass.
Is there a way to get emotion 11 to work with enzyme?
I also tried going this route:

  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      { "runtime": "automatic", "importSource": "@emotion/react" }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["@emotion/babel-plugin"]
}

And using the pragma in my component files
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from '@emotion/react'

But since I am on 16.8. of react and cannot change it, this doesn't work.
What can I do?
